# Can I have the selenium browser within a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium, chromium

Right now the chrome browser is separated from the WPF application and I would like to have the selenium browser within the WPF application. for example:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
DockPanel.Children.Add(driver);
```

Note that I'd also would like to use the selenium tools with it.

I did try using cefSharp but it will only create a chromiumWebBrowser and not a ChromeDriver

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: This is a long time ago. I did continue with two user interfaces. One was your own (wpf) the other one was the browser. You can create buttons in your wpf and manipulate what happens on the google browser. But having the browser within the wpf wasn't that necessary. Just a nice to have. But it's better to have the browser and the wpf (user interface) seperated.